# How to set a focus on a View with MVVM light

Tags: .net, silverlight, mvvm, focus, mvvm-light

Im using Silverlight 4 with MVVM light.
Let's say I have a MainView with two different data grids. if I select a row (SelectedItem) from any data grid, I can open a lightbox or a different MainView2. When closing the lightbox or navigating back from MainView2 to MainView, I would like the MainView to give focus to the  SelectedItem and its grid.

The only way I could think of doing so is to send messages between views or view models to set the focus.

Any other thoughts?

Thanks in advance,
Kruvi

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ready made example to show you. May be you can use the messanger to send a message saying the child view is closed. And in the parent set the focus to whichever control you would like. Alternately you can also fire an event from the child control which can be subscribed by the parent.

Personally I like the messanger approach as it keeps the solution decoupled. Having an event means the parent would be somewhat coupled with the child and could cause problems in scalability and maintainability of the application if its very large.

Hope this helps.